# Displaced buttons and labels. Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, label

I'm trying to do simple app like Quiz and I have displaced buttons and labels.
In storyboard I have it like this:

[image]

and in simulator:

[image]

Comment: This is probably auto layout behavior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your `UILabel` constraints are set to be centered inside the box.

Click the UILabel and check its constraints. If you set it to be centered vertical and horizontal with `constraints` (with its relative parent being the box) this should fix that problem for all size classes.

Comment: Can you post a picture of your text constraints?

Comment: Those are not constraints. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithConstraints/WorkingwithConstraints.html

Comment: Please read the documentation. That is just a pop up menu to set some constraints based on borders. The problem seems to be rooted in your lack of knowledge of constraints. My solution is correct, you need to set constraints properly. Read the documentation and learn how constraints work. It is essential to understand these if you are using AutoLayout.